# how to solve to @Autowired problem when starting Tomcat server?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

i would like to test a web service but i can't start my server due to this error

[image]

there is where i inserted the @Autowired annotation (in the controller)

```
          @RestController
          public class ProductController {

          @Autowired
         private ProductDao productDao;

        //Récupérer la liste des produits
         @RequestMapping(value="/Produits", method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public List<Product>listeProduits() {
          return productDao.findAll();
         }

        //Récupérer un produit par son Id
        @GetMapping(value="/Produits/{id}")
        public Product afficherUnProduit(@PathVariable int id) {
          return productDao.findById(id);
       }
        //ajouter un produit
        @PostMapping(value = "/Produits")
         public void ajouterProduit(@RequestBody Product product) {
        productDao.save(product);
       }
     }
```

and here is my interface ProductDao

```
        public interface ProductDao {

         public List<Product> findAll();
         public Product findById(int id);
         public Product save(Product product);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Repository` annotation at interface ProductDao and extend extends `CrudRepository<ENT, Long>`
Like below

```
@Repository
public interface ProductDao extends CrudRepository<ENT, Long>
```

//ENT is your primary key field name and Long is data type

You can take reference from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for better understanding